# Extract a lookup column with multiple values into another list using SharePoint Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a list "A" with many columns. One column is "Departments" that is a lookup column and allow multiple values.  After save the item, I want to copy each value of "Departments" to another list "B" with 2 columns 'BID' and 'Dept'. Can I do it in SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Example:

List A:

IDNumber: 2

Departments: Math; Bio; Engineering

List B:

BID: 2

Dept: Math

BID: 2

Dept: Bio

BID: 2

Dept: Engineering

I was thinking to extract 'Departments' first, then do a loop to save each one in the list B.  I'm not very familiar with SharePoint Designer Workflow.  How to extract lookup column? How to do a loop to save the data to list B?
Appreciate for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

First I am not sure about how BID shall change with the List A. More information may be helpful.

Then for looping multi-selection look up column, we will need to first have Platform 2013 workflow. In other words, in your farm, workflow manager needs to be deployed. Without it, we cannot use 2013 workflow. The default 2010 workflow does not support adding a loop and call http request. Here is a [tutorial](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/a8a890b5-f5fb-447f-b96f-9f3abdb7e178/forum-faq-sharepoint-2013-extracting-values-from-a-multivalue-enabled-lookup-column-and-merge?forum=sharepointgeneral) with a similar scenario using 2013 workflow which you can refer to.

And if you are using SharePoint Online, I will suggest using Power Automate which will provide easier solution to do similar thing.